# I need some help getting an extra match group in a regex where the current match results in duplicates

Tags: regex

I started with a Javascript regex that matched the phrase correctly but it turns out that depending on the strings, it is sometime matching it twice so it appears like a duplicate.
What I would like to do is extend my match to add an extra grouping so that it picks up the Paragraph name as a group.
Line returns are also complicating my current match since the regex needs to look across multiple lines

My current regex is: https://regex101.com/r/ykwW1j/1

> \WReturn Amount\W[^"]*specified in\s([^"]*)\sof this Annex

My current string is:

> random other text earlier in the document
>
> Paragraph 13. Variables.
>
> (B) "Return Amount" has the meaning specified in Paragraph 3(b) of
> this Annex.
>
> (A) "Delivery Amount" has the meaning specified in Paragraph 3(a) of
> this Annex.
>
> Paragraph 14. Elections and Variables - blahs.
>
> (A) "Delivery Amount" has the meaning specified in Paragraph 3(a) of
> this Annex.
>
> (8) "Return Amount" has the meaning specified in Paragraph 3(b) of
> this Annex.
>
> (A) "Delivery Amount" has the meaning specified in Paragraph 3(a) of
> this Annex.
>
> random other text later in the document

The current matches are:

> Match 1
>
> Full match    76-149  "Return Amount" has the meaning specified
> in Paragraph 3(b) of this Annex
>
> Group 1.  121-135 Paragraph 3(b)
>
> Match 2
>
> Full match    372-445`"Return Amount" has the meaning specified
> in Paragraph 3(b) of this Annex
>
> Group 1.  417-431 Paragraph 3(b)

What I want to end up with here is an extra Group. So, the result would look something like the below. The second match has a slight difference in paragraph number change from 13 to 14.

> Match 1
>
> Group 1.    xxx-xxx Paragraph 13
>
> Group 2.  121-135 Paragraph 3(b)
>
> Match 2
>
> Group 1.    xxx-xxx Paragraph **14**
>
> Group 2.  417-431 Paragraph 3(b)

How can I add line returns, carriage returns and the extra grouping into this regex?

For example, I tried this but it only matches the first one in Paragraph 13:

> Paragraph [0-9][0-9][^"]*\WReturn Amount\W[^"]*specified
> in\s([^"]*)\sof this Annex

Comment: Your current regex does not match the string at all because you're excluding `"` quotes from the place where quotes are right after `Return Amount`... see your `\WReturn Amount\W[^"]specified...`

Comment: Click the link to regex 101, it does match them

Comment: Not in the code you posted in the question (post all relevant code in the question itself, not on an external site)

Comment: It's exactly the same, no? I'll recheck it

Comment: please provide your input string and expected output result

Comment: It's above, the string is in the 2nd blockquote, the result is in the last

Comment: The regex in your question is `\WReturn Amount\W[^"]specified in\s([^"])\sof this Annex` but the regex in your link is `\WReturn Amount\W[^"]*specified in\s([^"]*)\sof this Annex` (`*` mangled)

Comment: Try [`/^(Paragraph +\d+)(?:(?!^Paragraph \d)[\s\S])*?"Return Amount"[\s\S]*?(Paragraph +\d+\(\w+\)|$(?!.))/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/Q48AUF/2). This regex is not efficient, but it may be enhanced later if it does what you need.

Comment: Or , see https://regex101.com/r/eH7ywm/7  if there must be `of this annex`.

Answer (score 0):

The regex `^(Paragraph \d+).*?"Return Amount".*?(Paragraph \S+)` with multi-line (so that `^` can match the beginning of every line) and single-line (so that `.` can match newline characters) matching options enabled will do.

See: https://regex101.com/r/ykwW1j/2

Comment: perfect. Thanks!

Comment: One problem with that one. If the page only has paragraph 14 then it doesn't match it. Paragraph 13 by itself is matched even if paragraph 14 doesn't exist https://regex101.com/r/wRLflS/2

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by a page with only paragraph 14. Do you mean a page with only paragraph 14 but no `"Return Amount" has the meaning specified in Paragraph 3(b) of this Annex.` that follows?

Comment: Added link above late

Comment: Like I mentioned in my answer, you need to enable the single-line matching option in order for `.` to match a newline character. See: https://regex101.com/r/wRLflS/3

Comment: Hmm. Single line mode doesn't seem to work in javascript. Trying ^(Paragraph \d+).*?"Return Amount".*?(Paragraph \S+)\s\S

Comment: Ok got it, I add [\s\S] in place of the dot